# ASP.NET MVC C#: My View "Create" causes a 404 error every time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

This is my first ASP.NET MVC application and one of my views keeps causing a 404 error. I have 4 views and "Create" is the only view that is not working. I tried recreating the view "Create" because it was suggested in another post on here.

But that did not work for me.

**PhoneController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PhoneVM model)
{
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.Id = model.Id;
        phone.Name = model.Name;
        phone.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
        PhoneRepository phoneRepository = new PhoneRepository();
        phoneRepository.SavePhone(phone);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model PhoneBook.ViewModels.PhoneVM

@ {
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

![structure]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kutsy.jpg

![When I try to access it] https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLuOI.jpg

I have some more html code in `Create.cshtml`, but I don't think that is relevant.

Mby I have just starred my self blind on this over the last few hours and forgot some little thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your `Create` action method you are not returning a `View()` rather redirecting to different action `Index` and most probably there is no such action method called `Index` in your `Phone` controller

```
public ActionResult Create(PhoneVM model)
{
    .....
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I have a method in my PhoneController called Index, the index is where all the phones are showed. I have a View called EditPhone, and in my PhoneController it also redirects to Index, but my EditPhone page works just fine. It just redirects to Index when ur done on that page. But i will try returning a View instead then

Comment: return view() did not work for me, just gave me the same error

Comment: I forgot the return view() another place in my code, so u pointed me in the right direction. Thanks man!